# Verilog Calculator w/ 16 bit signed inputs

Tags: verilog, xilinx, hdl, circuit

I need to build a calculator that takes 2 signed 16 bit numbers (in1, in2) and preforms functions on them depending on the opCode (a 4 bit input). The outputs should be a signed 16 bit number named 'result' and one bit 'overflow'

I really need help fixing my code. It's not working and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

opCode

1. 0000.....Add in1 and in2
2. 0001.....subtract in1-in2
3. 0010.....divide in1 by ten with remainder of 1 or zero (use modulus operator)
4. 0011.....bitwise AND in1 in2
5. 0100.....bitwise xOR in1 |in2
6. 0101.....complement in1
7. 0110.....bitwise OR in1 in2
8. 0111.....complement in1
9. 1000.....increment in1 by 1
10. 1001....decrement in1 by 1

    ```
    module calculator(
        input [15:0] in1,
        input [15:0] in2,
        input [3:0] opCode,
        output [15:0]
        );
        reg [3:0] opCode;
        reg [15:0] in1;
        reg [15:0] in2;
        reg [15:0] result;   
        reg overflow;


    always @ (opcode) begin 
        if (opCode == 0000) begin // add in1+in2
            result=in1+in2; 
                          $display("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, in2, result, overflow);
                $monitor("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, in2, result, overflow);
         end
        if (opCode == 0001) begin   //subtract in1-in3
         result=in1-in2; 
                $display("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, in2, result, overflow);
                $monitor("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, in2, result, overflow);
                 end


        if (opCode == 0011) begin   //divide int1 by 10 w/ remainder as overflow
         result=in1%10; 
                $display("opCode(%b),in1(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, result, overflow);
                $monitor("opCode(%b),in1(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, result, overflow);
                 end


        if (opCode == 0100) begin   //preforms AND operation in1 in2
         result=in1&int2; 
                $display("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1,in2, result, overflow);
                $monitor("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1,in2, result, overflow);
                 end


        if (opCode == 0101) begin   //preforms XOR operation in1 in2
         result=in1^int2; 
                $display("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1,in2, result, overflow);
                $monitor("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1,in2, result, overflow);
                 end


        if (opCode == 0110) begin   //preforms OR op on in1 in 2
         result=in1|int2; 
                $display("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1,in2, result, overflow);
                $monitor("opCode(%b),in1(%d),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1,in2, result, overflow);
                 end


        if (opCode == 0111) begin   //complement of in1
         result=!in1; 
                $display("opCode(%b),in1(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, result, overflow);
                $monitor("opCode(%b),in1(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, result, overflow);
                 end


        if (opCode == 1001) begin   //increase in1 by 1
         result=in1+1; 
                $display("opCode(%b),in1(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, result, overflow);
                $monitor("opCode(%b),in1(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in1, result, overflow);
                 end


        if (opCode == 1000) begin   //decrease in2 by 1
         result=in2-1; 
                $display("opCode(%b),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in2, result, overflow);
                $monitor("opCode(%b),in2(%d),result(%d),overflow(%b)", opCode, in2, result, overflow);
                 end


    end
     end
     endmodule


     endmodule
    ```

Comment: Try `always @*` instead of `always @ (opcode)`. Learn the difference between `$display` and `$monitor`. Your code might benefit with a case statement.

Comment: Just noticed there are several obvious compiling errors too. Review your log file.

Answer (score 1):

I have highlighted a couple of issues :

```
module calculator(
  input [15:0] in1, //<-- title says inputs are signed
  input [15:0] in2,
  input [3:0] opCode,
  output [15:0] //<-- undeclared name
);
reg [3:0] opCode;
reg [15:0] in1; //<-- inputs can not be reg
reg [15:0] in2;
reg [15:0] result;   
reg overflow;
```

Should probably be :

```
module calculator(
  input      signed [15:0] in1,
  input      signed [15:0] in2,
  input              [3:0] opCode,
  output reg signed [15:0] result
);  
reg overflow;
```